# SweetAlert2: Set dialog height

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, sweetalert

for sweetAlert2 I noticed there's no "height" property but there is a "width" property, is there a way to set the height of the dialog to be 80%?

Thanks

https://limonte.github.io/sweetalert2/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have to use a custom CSS class like in the snippet below:

```js
const test = () => {
  swal({
     title: 'Test',
     customClass: 'swal-height'
  });

};
```

```css
.swal-height {
  height: 80vh;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert2@7.1.2/dist/sweetalert2.all.js"></script>

<button onclick="test()">test</button>
```

Comment: Just an update on this, when using the customClass on newer versions of sweet alert you can change the height with the content property of the customClass option.

you can use this snippet:

swal.fire({
customClass: { 
content: 'custom-class'
}
})

Answer (score 3):

Since version 7.21.0 a fix is added. You can add the option "heightAuto: false" to your Sweet Alert options and the problem is solved.

```
Swal.fire({
    heightAuto: false,
    title: 'Hello,
    Text: 'This is an alert'
});
```

Example here: https://jsfiddle.net/y3nf3fjg/1/

Comment: This fiddle seems to point to a solution to a different problem.

Answer (score 1):

The only way that works for me to customize css of SweetAlert is to override them (including !important) at the global styles.scss file.

exp:

```
.swal2-popup {
  font-size: 1em !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using angular.I changed from "height:100%" to "height:100vh"
(in MainComponent.scss). This solution works for me.

```
<body>
 <app-main>
 </app-main>
</body>
```

main.component.scss

```
:host
{height:100vh}
```